# Erro ao Conectar PostgreSQL ao Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, npgsql

Estou tentando conectar o EF no Postgresql. Está apresentando a seguinte mensagem:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: Ocorreu um erro ao criar o manipulador de
>   seção de configuração de system.data: A coluna 'InvariantName' está
>   restrita a conter valores exclusivos. O valor 'Npgsql' já existe.

Minha Classe Context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Npgsql;

namespace TesteEnti
{
    class testeBD: DbContext
    {

        public testeBD()
            : base("TesteDB")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Meu APP Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
            invariant="Npgsql"
            description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
            type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="TesteDB" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=postgres;password=flavio123;database=testedb" providerName="Npgsql"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Tenho os pacotes instalados, EF e NPGSQL EF.

O que eu poderia fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Tire a tag dbProvidersFactory inteira do web.config e teste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisar adicionar a tag `remove`  antes da tag `add`, para caso de já existir o provider ele remover e depois adicionar novamente.

```
 <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
            invariant="Npgsql"
            description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
            type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
```

Comment: Deu certo obrigado, mas como posso trocar para que ele nao salve como um DBO e sim no schema que eu desejo  ? Pois ele pega de padrão do SQLSERVER o DBO.

Comment: Você pode utilizar isso  [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("[nome da sua tabela]", Schema = "public")]

Comment: Sim fiz dessa forma , só que ainda criar uma shema DBO com uma tabela de migration. Como posso remover isso para que seja tudo no schema public?

Comment: NO seu DbContext  Insere esta linha `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");` no método `OnModelCreating` Ficando assim: `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }`